# parse dataframe into class without duplicating the dataframe in memory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory-management

I have a pandas dataframe that i want to process, preferably with a class. The dataframe is large.

```
# some data
symbol_1 = 10000
symbol_2 = 10001
df = pd.DataFrame("some large dataframe")


# create a class to process the data
class Calc_stats:
    "statistics on the symbol """

    def __init__(self, symbol, df):
        ''' initialise the class '''

        self.symbol = symbol
        self.df = df


# instantate class
stats_1 = Calc_stats(symbol_1, df)
stats_2 = Calc_stats(symbol_2, df)
```

So my question is this: will i have replicated the (large) df in memmory for each instance of the class that is created ?

ie. Is the code left with 3 dataframes, `df`, `stats_1.df` and `stats_2.df` or is there just one df used where the other two instances point to the first ?

Comment: There is only one `df` the other two refers to the first,  you can validate this by checking `id(df) == id(stats_1.df) == id(stats_2.df)` which should return `True`

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you copy the dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You can test if those Dataframes are the same object in memory by using the `id()` function, or by creating both objects, modifying the original dataframe, and then checking the objects' attributes for those changes.

If you are worried about duplicating big data structures or objects, you can always remove the attribute from your class and instead create functions that handle extracting relevant data from those Dataframes.

Comment: this is useful. I posted a second answer below which proves the same, but is longer than using `ID()`

Answer (score 0):

In testing.  I created a sample dataframe and then edited an element of one of the instance dataframes and then `print(df)` the original dataframe and verify that it was changed.

This means that there is just one dataframe (and not 3 copies of the same).

It is also noted from @Yaels answer that the `ID()` function can be used.